# How to understand crossover Git log?

Tags: git, github, git-log

May anyone tell me what happended between 0ab11dd and bd7278a?
And also between 27ac7b7 and 95b2c48?
Why there is crossover in those commits?

```
* xxxxxxx (HEAD -> f-1, origin/f-1) 
* xxxxxxx fix merge conflicts
*   13751d5 Merge branch 'master' into feature/DP-1
|\  
| *   f3efc9d (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge pull request #9 from fix
| |\  
| | * 83c0b15 (origin/fix) 
| |/  
| *   be24ce6 Merge pull request 
| |\  
| | *   0ab11dd merge
| | |\  
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * |   bd7278a Merge pull request 
| |\ \  
| | * | 14399e2 
| | | * xxxxxxx  
| | | * xxxxxxx 
| | | *   27ac7b7 merge
| | | |\  
| | |_|/  
| |/| |   
| | | * 95b2c48 (origin/f-3) 
| | | * xxxxxxx
```

especially this

```
| | |_|/  
| |/| |
```

why there is an out branch but no commit?

Comment: Are `0ab11dd` and `27ac7b7` actually merge commits? (As a sidenote, *this* is why commit messages matter)

Comment: @RomainValeri yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the "crossovers"**

This is just the way the graphic tool represents merges : from right to left (the one on the left being the one "receiving" the merge). So when a commit series (rather than say branch which may be confusing here) has to be merged into another which happens to be currently graphically represented to its right, then the tool draws a line which, yes, crosses the other ones to make its junction to the merge commit *from the right*.

**So it's just a graphical convention.**

---

**About the vertical lines** *(after comments)*

Branches are (optionnally, with --decorate) added to the graph at the commit they're currently pointing to, but don't forget that your repo tree doesn't really need any of them. These commit series are the body of your tree, where "branches" are in fact just the tips, that's where the metaphor breaks down a little bit...

---

*(I grant you that it's a very low-tech representation, ...but let's also admit that informative commit messages would make things way clearer.)*

Comment: so one  "vertical" line doesn't necessarily mean a branch? then how can I tell how many branches in total? And does the color indicates anything about branch?

Comment: @wwwwan Colors help distinguish between your local branches (green), remote-tracking branches (red) which are images of remote ones, and tags (yellow). To check your branches list, try [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), namely with `-a` to see not only local branches but also remote-tracking ones.

Comment: "Branches are (optionnally, with --decorate) added to the graph at the commit they're currently pointing to ". so will the commits in the same branch (Except merge) in the same vertical line?

Comment: @wwwwan This is a deep misunderstanding (but be reassured, you're not the only one to struggle with it, this is the key point to grasp). No commit is "on" any branch. Branches are disposable, commits are permanent. A branch only names a commit. From *this* commit, you can retrace back through ancestry down to the first initial commit. Commits are said *reachable* through many (or zero) branches.

Comment: @RomainValeri: the way I like to put it is that commits are "on" *many* branches, but the set of branches that they are "on"—or that contain them, which is kind of a better way to express this— *changes* as you modify branch labels. The commits stay put (as you said) while the labels move around, hence the reachability issue you mention.

Comment: @torek Yes, this is also how I try to represent it to myself. (The main reason being... that I learned it from you, like most things git.) But this is confusing many people, I'm still quite early in my own learning process but I can remember having had to explain it to quite a few people already... I'm amazed that you still find the patience to break it down daily to everyone...

Answer (score 1):

This would be a comment, but there's not room and it needs formatting.

The section at this point:

```
| | | *   27ac7b7 merge
| | | |\  
| | |_|/  
| |/| |   
| | | * 95b2c48 (origin/f-3) 
| | | * xxxxxxx
```

is incomplete.  If you keep going through the graph, it may eventually resolve itself like this:

```
| | | * xxxxxxx 
| | |/
| | * yyyyyyy
| |/
| * zzzzzzz
|/
* sssssss
```

(but we can't really guess and it's probably much more complicated than that).

With enough additional graph we can say more about commit `27ac7b7`.  At the moment all we know is that it is a merge, with two parents, and the first parent is `95b2c48` (which is labeled `origin/f-3`).  We cannot see the second parent commit's hash ID here, but following the graph line, you would eventually arrive at the second parent.

(The first commit you asked about—`0ab11dd`—is a merge commit with parents `xxxxxxx`, the result of following the direct-downward line to that commit, and commit `bd7278a`, the result of following the line that initially descends rightward then immediately reverses and crosses down to `bd7278a`.  `git log --graph` emphasizes the first/not-first relationships of parentage by drawing the not-first links out towards the right.  Some graph drawing methods, including the one I usually use, don't make the distinction at all.  When and whether the distinction is useful is another topic, but see the `--first-parent` option to `git log`.)